# how to add application to initrd.gz

Tags: linux, initramfs, initrd, ramdisk

I have an `initrd.gz` (from linux parag*n live cd)
I want to edit the file inside and add app like apache,ophcrack,etc.
So far I've done extracting by following these step wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomizeLiveInitrd (btw, the `initrd.gz` not come from ubuntu)

So I have dir named `initrd-tmp/` and contain all files and folder from `initrd.gz` and I have a file called `httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz` (apache). 
So how to add this app?

Answer (score 1):

`httpd.tar.gz` file are extracted using `tar -xzf httpd.tar.gz`.

Edit/add file in directory `httpd` ,

- then rebuild archive using `tar czf http.tar.gz httpd`
- then rebuild initrd (uncompressed) usind `find . -type f -print | cpio -o -H newc > ../initrd2.cpio`
- then compress initrd : `gzip initrd2.cpio`
- then put it back in place.